# Why does this work? Adding UILabel in repeat loop

Tags: swift, uilabel

I'm an absolute swift beginner and trying to build my first app. When I write a bit of code I don't expect it to work first time and am suspicious when it does. In a repeat loop I was setting lines on a graph and wanted to add a UILabel to the left of the line. I thought I could `let` a new UILabel to create a subview of the main view but didn't know how to get it to create a unique variable name for each iteration.

```
repeat {
        // code to make the lines here

        // create label with minute number for each line
        let minuteLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))

        // code to position the label here

        minuteLabel.text = String(numberOfLines)

        // code to style the label

        self.addSubview(minuteLabel)

        numberOfLines--
    }
    while numberOfLines > 0
```

I thought this would end up just creating the one subview and its text would be the last iteration of numberOfLines but it worked perfectly. Does this mean my main graphing view now has (numberOfLines) number of UILabel subviews each with the same name?

Is it possible to access each individually outside the scope of this repeat loop?

Thanks for helping me understand this!

Comment: Sometimes code does work the first time, surprises me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is important to distinguish between the attributes of an object and references to an object. When you write "number of UILabel subviews each with the same name" that is not an accurate phrase because those labels *do not have names*. An object (a label in this case) has no information about how many references might exist to it or what those references might have been named at compile time.

In your code example you create a constant reference `minuteLabel` and assign it to point to a label. That constant exists only within the scope of one iteration of that `repeat` loop. At the end of the current loop iteration that reference is discarded. Without a reference to the label object you may no longer be able to locate it but that does not mean the label does not still exist. In this case you added the label as a subview of some other view (`self`). That parent view created its own strong reference to the label and as per the rules of [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) that label will continue to exist as long as there is a strong reference to it. You could even find these labels again using `self.subviews` however you may have a hard time figuring out which label is which now that you no longer have a reference to each one.

It might also be helpful to note that while the name you give a reference (like `minuteLabel`) is meaningful to you it is not meaningful or even known to the computer running your app. That name helps us humans keep track of a specific location in the computer's memory which happens point to a `UILabel` but you won't be able to use the same name to locate the same label from some other scope in your code. Your app could have many references named `minuteLabel` in different scopes and they could even point to different types of objects, having the same name does not make them the same thing.

In a case like there where you have a collection of objects and want to be able to locate each one again later a good solution is usually to use some sort of collection type; an array would allow you to store references to these labels in a known order and you could then look up the label at a specific index, a dictionary would allow you to store references to these labels under some known "key" object and you could later use an equivalent key to retrieve a specific label.

You will not find great success attempting to dynamically create a variable of constant for each object (e.g. a loop that creates a `minuteLabel0` constant and then a `minuteLabel1` constant, ...). If it is not clear why then it might be worth building a more precise mental model of the difference between the compilation and execution phases of your program.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it a lot clearer. In this case at the moment I don't think I'll need to reference them again - they're more just set and forget but I'm sure in the future I'll create something like this and would have struggled to figure out how to access them again!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly suviews are not referenced to by name so they wont all have the same name. They are contained in an array that can be accessed by reference to the index. So when your adding each subview it is added to the appropriate array and for example is accessed by:

```
self.subviews[0]
```

each each element will then hold that same subview you are creating in the loop. Hope this helps clear it up for you.